# validate constructor arguments or method parameters with annotations, and let them throw an exception automatically

Tags: java, exception, annotations

I am validating constructor and method arguments, as I want to the software, especially the model part of it, to fail fast.

As a result, constructor code often looks like this

```
public MyModelClass(String arg1, String arg2, OtherModelClass otherModelInstance) {
    if(arg1 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentsException("arg1 must not be null");
    }
    // further validation of constraints...
    // actual constructor code...
}
```

Is there a way to do that with an annotation driven approach? Something like:

```
public MyModelClass(@NotNull(raise=IllegalArgumentException.class, message="arg1 must not be null") String arg1, @NotNull(raise=IllegalArgumentException.class) String arg2, OtherModelClass otherModelInstance) {

    // actual constructor code...
}
```

In my eyes this would make the actual code a lot more readable.

In understand that there are annotations in order to support IDE validation (like the existing @NotNull annotation).

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using asserts in the public method for checking parameters is not a good idea. During the compilation process all asserts can be eliminated from the code so no checks will be performed at the runtime. The Better solution here would be using a validating framework such as Apache Commons. In this case your code might be:

```
public MyModelClass(String arg1, String arg2, OtherModelClass otherModelInstance) {
    org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notNull(arg1, "arg1 must not be null");
    // further validation of constraints...
    // actual constructor code...
}
```

Comment: It has been two existing years full of software development. Wanting to let you know that I think this is actually the best way to do it, if you are in a server java environment (i.e. not Android or similar), so you can easily add third party libs

Answer (score 1):

Such frameworks do exist (JSR-330), but firstly, I would debate that the annotation approach is more readable. Something like this would seem better to me:

```
public MyModelClass(String arg1, String arg2, OtherModelClass otherModelInstance) {
    Assert.notNull(arg1, "arg1 must not be null");
    // further validation of constraints...
    // actual constructor code...
}
```

where `Assert.notNull` is a static method somewhere (and as provided in the likes of Spring or Commons Lang).

But assuming you're convinced with using annotations, have a look at [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html), which is the reference implementation of the JSR-330 API. This has annotations like the ones you describe.

The problem here is that you need the framework to interpret those annotations. Just calling `new MyModelClass()` isn't going to do that without some classloading magic under the covers.

The likes of [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about) can use JSR-330 annotations to validate the data in models, so you could [have a look at that](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation), but that may not be suitable for your situation. Something similar is going to be necessary, though, else the annotations are nothing more than decoration.

Comment: In fact I'm using spring a lot. Thank you for your help.

Maybe you're right and the static "Assert.notNull" approach is the more readable one.